# Google Analytics to Excel or SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, google-analytics

Can anyone please help me to export the data from Google Analytics to an Excel file or SQL Server using C#?

It would be great if someone can provide with any examples.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to stack unfortunately we cant direct you to things like that you need to search on your own and come back with issues.   I am the lead developer on TARGIT Google Analytics we offer a custom SSIS connection manager and data reader which will let you extract the data yourself http://www.targit.com/en/resources/store/datareaderforgoogleanalytics I also have a number of tutorials on how to access the data yourself using C# http://www.daimto.com/category/googleanalytics/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the Reply. I am new to Google Analytics. I am not sure how to export the data from Google Analytics daily Automatically. My ultimate goal is to get the data from Google Analytics and save it to a database table on sql server. I tried to use SSIS Google Analytics Source but no luck. So I am looking for any other options. Any help would be greatly appreciated.